# List output formatting in a variable

Tags: python-2.7

I made a Email Bot that crawls Craigslist and emails me when an item meets my queries.  I am at the final stage and have everything working but my email format.

What I have is a loop that appends Craigslist Listings to a list.  Outside my loop I add the List to my email Def as an argument.

Example of what I need:

```
list = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
print list
['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] # I don't want it on a single line
for i in list:
     print i
item1
item2
item3
#I want a variable with the single line item format.
```

I want the single line format placed into a Variable rather than as the list.  My list could be 1 item or 20, depends on what has been posted on Craigslist.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `str.join` you can join a list by the string given:

```
"\n".join(my_list)
```

If you need more fancy formatting than a string per line you should look at a combination of join and [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format)

P.S.: By the way, don't shadow the "list" builtin, that's bad practice. It will lead to errors whenever you want to use the builtin.

Comment: Second issue, can i put this in a variable.  if i do "print "\n".join(mylist) it works but if i do x = "\n".join(mylist) i come up with 'see\ncat\nrun'

Comment: You need to print the value too, of course. i.e. `print '\n'.join(my_list)

Comment: Upvote and accept if I could help you. Would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Grateful-Fisherman You have to `print` that variable. If you just echo it in an interactive session, it will again use the `repr` format for that variable, i.e. including quotes and explicit line breaks. In an interactive session, do `>>> print x` instead of just `>>> x`.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you are asking. As I understand the question, you want to print the list items on different lines, but in the same style as used when printing the list in one line.

The `__str__` method of a container class usually uses the `__repr__` method of the contained objects, so if you want to print the items on several lines in the same style as when you print it in one line, use the `repr` function to get the result of `__repr__`.

```
>>> lst = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
>>> for i in lst:
...     print repr(i)
... 
'item1'
'item2'
'item3'
```

Comment: I'm fine with all that, I want that in a variable so I can add it to an argument.  My email script takes 1 argument which is the content of the email.  It will look like this: email(list) # with the format of single lines... does that make any sense?  I would post my code but i'm at work and it cannot get into my google drive.